# How to loosen up required versions when installing a package

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, anonymize

There is a python anonymization package called cape-privace.
When I try to pip install it, it gives and error due to conflicting packages,
For example it requires pandas==1.0.3, but it successfully work with pandas latest version.

How can I access cape-privacy setup settings and what should I change so it installs successfully

As for now, I keep getting this error.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I see you have posted on that project's github repo and the maintainers haven't responded.
The installation is indeed broken, and its possible it only works for specific operating systems or specific versions of python.
I would try running it in docker and try to figure out why it works in their setup. Otherwise you will have to figure out how to figure out how to fix the installation of cape-privacy by editing the Makefile, requirements.txt and supporting scripts.

```
docker run -it capeprivacy/cape-python:0.3.0 bash
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I already figured out the way out. I cloned the their repo and edited the setup.py file. I changed  "pandas~=1.0.3" to "pandas" and then in terminal run sudo python3 setup.py install and it worked. 
I plan on using cape-privacy in my own package, how can I apply this changes in a way that when the user installs my packages he also install the cape-privacy I have (with edited setup.py file)